# How to improve separation of concerns in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code that uses `html data attributes` instead of `jquery class name selectors` as advised in [Classnames for styling, data attributes for behavior](http://blog.realstuffforabstractpeople.com/post/31753521367/classnames-for-styling-data-attributes-for-behavior). This code is working fine.  However, it refers the html5 data attributes in the javascript file.

Example

```
$("[data-role='show-alert']").click(function () {
//and
textValue = $("[data-role='employee-name-text']").val();
```

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to avoid this reference of html5 data attributes in javascript file?  (By using a model or something?)

Note: I am using **`Kendo UI`** framework.

**Head**

```
<head>
    <title>HTML 5 Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //CONTROLLER File  
        var textValue = '';

        function getEmployeeBusinessFunction() {

            var currentEmployeeName = textValue;
            alert(currentEmployeeName);
        }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("[data-role='show-alert']").click(function () {

                //textValue = $('.myPersonTextbox').val();
                textValue = $("[data-role='employee-name-text']").val();

                //Call Business Function
                getEmployeeBusinessFunction();

            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
```

**Body**

```
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" class='myPersonTextbox' name="personName" placeholder="Employee Name" data-role='employee-name-text' />
    <button type="button" class='myButton' data-role='show-alert'>
        Add</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [docs.telerik.com - How To Use Kendo UI Declarative Initialization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/howto/declarative_initialization)
2. [docs.telerik.com - MVVM / Declarative Initialization And HTML5 Data Attributes](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-03-20/mvvm_declarative_initialization_and_html5_data_attributes)
3. [classnames for styling, data attributes for behavior](http://blog.realstuffforabstractpeople.com/post/31753521367/classnames-for-styling-data-attributes-for-behavior)
4. [Don't use class names to find HTML elements with JS](http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/dont-use-class-names-to-find-HTML-elements-with-JS.html)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the data attributes in javascript, so I'm a little confused by the question. However, they're generally used to associate data with the elements they're set on and accessed to retrieve that data rather than to just select elements with. FYI, the jQuery .data() method is a simple way of retrieving or setting those values as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use thouse attributes even if they are part of HTML5 - thats what they are for. Especially if no conflicts expected.

If you still want to get rid of naming conflicts, you may use namespaces with selectors like

```
$('myns\\:[data-role='show-alert']') 
...
<myns:button type="button" class='myButton' data-role='show-alert'>
```

to avoid selecting HTML5 attributes which are not related to your code.